# Batch delete: Access is denied

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch

I'm having issues with the `del` command in a batch file. When it gets to the delete step I get the message "Access is denied". My batch command looks something like this.

```
set destPath=\\Public01\Appl\CompOps\Jobs\

robocopy . "%destPath%" *.dtsx *.dev *.prod *.ppro /IS

pushd "%destPath%"
del *.dtsConfig
ren *.dev .
popd
```

[image]

I can browse to the directory and delete the files without any problem in [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer).

I tried running as administrator, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To force a [`del`](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) command to delete read-only files, add the `/F` flag.

Apparently, a read-only file cannot normally be deleted by a batch file, although it can still be deleted through [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer). To check if your file is read-only, you can right click on the file and select properties, or enter [`attrib <filename>`](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) at the command prompt. This will show a series of letters corresponding to different file attributes.

```
R = Read-only file
A = Archive file
S = System file
H = Hidden file
```

You can remove the read-only tag by unchecking the box in the properties window or running the command `attrib <filename> -R`.

Comment: unfortunately that does not fix the problem, i'll update my question to include your suggestion though.

Comment: Try putting `pause` before the `del` command, and then try deleting it through Windows Explorer while it's paused.

Comment: I found the solution, however if you wish to edit your answer to include some suggestions in addition to my solution I'd be happy to mark it as the answer

Comment: Alright, is that information retroactively helpful? :)

Comment: I'm sure it will be helpful when I forget about this problem months from now :)

Comment: `attrib` works, but it also works using the "/A" option for `del`. E.g. adding `/A:H` for successfully deleting *.suo files that (often) have the "hidden" file attribute. See [`del`](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html)

Answer (score 2):

After experimenting with the options available to the "del" command I discovered that the files I was attempting to delete were read-only. To resolve the problem I could either edit the files to remove the read-only attribute, or specify the /F option.

Final script is

```
set destPath=\\Public01\Appl\CompOps\Jobs\

robocopy . "%destPath%" *.dtsx *.dev *.prod *.ppro /IS

pushd "%destPath%"
del /F *.dtsConfig
ren *.dev .
popd
```

Simple solution, but a misleading error message. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: If you can only read it, an access denied sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for my Windows 8.1 PC:

First of all close Windows Explorer by:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> for opening *[Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager)*, go to processes, find *Windows Explorer*, right click, and *end task*. Don't worry if start bar is gone and something else. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for traversing between files. Then in *Task Manager* click *File* and *Run new task*, and type `cmd`. This will open you a *Command Line*.

Inside the *Terminal*:

If your version is 32 bit, and it is in my case, it's located in *Program Files (x86)*, so you should type:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah"
regsvr32 /u git_shell_ext64.dll
```

This was for unregistering.

You can traverse between directories using `cd directoryname` and you can get back one directory by `cd ..`. For viewing what is in a directory you can type `dir` in when you are in that directory. For deleting the file type:

```
del /F filename
```

After that again open the *Task Manager*, go to *File*, then run `explorer` .
This way you will get to usual display. Go to the *Git* folder which we wanted to get rid of and delete it simply.

I hope this works for other people who are using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem and turned out Avast was denying my batch file. All I had to do was add the .bat file to the exception list on Avast.